# Sorting an array according to a key in multi dimensional array and preserving other key values. PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

This is my array.

```
Array
        (
            [Data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [recipeid] => 108
                            [recipe] => Rasams- the tongue ticklers ! 
                            [image] => No data
                            [category] => Rasams and Soups
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [recipeid] => 44
                            [recipe] => Brain Booster- do you want to try it?
                            [image] => brain-booster-do-you-44-HP-62.jpg
                            [category] => Drinks and Smoothies
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [recipeid] => 36
                            [recipe] => Pineapple Grape Smoothy--a rare combo
                            [image] => pineapple-grape-smoo-36-HP-62.jpg
                            [category] => Drinks and Smoothies
                        )

                )

        )
```

I have to sort [DATA] array according to alphabetical order of [key]recipe's value, also preserve the recipeid, image, category after sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use usort.

```
usort($yourarray['Data'], 'data_sort');

function data_sort($a, $b) {
  return (strcasecmp($a['recipe'], $b['recipe']) > 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with [usort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).  Here's an example of how it could be done, based off of the example given in the PHP docs.

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['recipe'] == $b['recipe']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['recipe'] < $b['recipe']) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($a, "cmp");
```